# Install additional packages that provide Bluetooth low energy and router capabilities

Tags: software-installation, bluetooth

I want to install the following packages under 2015-05-05-raspbian-wheezy:

bluez, libcap-ng0 & radvd

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install bluez radvd libcap-ng0
```

then I run

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo dpkg -i bluez_4.99-2_armhf.deb libcap-ng0_0.6.6-2_armhf.deb radvd_1.8.5-1_armhf.deb
```

but I got these errors .. any idea ?

```
dpkg: error processing bluez_4.99-2_armhf.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing libcap-ng0_0.6.6-2_armhf.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing radvd_1.8.5-1_armhf.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bluez_4.99-2_armhf.deb
 libcap-ng0_0.6.6-2_armhf.deb
 radvd_1.8.5-1_armhf.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

This command:

```
sudo apt-get install bluez radvd libcap-ng0
```

Will download *and install* those packages.  If it completes successfully, there's nothing more to do.

This command:

```
sudo dpkg -i bluez_4.99-2_armhf.deb
```

Will install that package, presuming it is in the current directory.  If not, it will say "No such file or directory".  Generally you should not have to use `dpkg` at all; it would only be in the rare case where you have a package not available in a repo but which can still be installed on your distro (sometimes people distribute independent things pre-packaged this way).

So I presume you've gotten a bit confused about how these two commands relate.  `apt-get` essentially does what `dpkg` does but without you ever having to see the package file it downloaded (those are likely in the filesystem afterward, see `/var/cache/apt/archives`, but again, this is not something you have to use or worry about).